# How to get xyz coordinates from a selected component in viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

```js
var viewer;
 var options = {
     env: 'AutodeskProduction',
     api: 'derivativeV2',  // for models uploaded to EMEA change this option to 'derivativeV2_EU'
     getAccessToken: function(onTokenReady) {
         var token = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Imp3dF9zeW1tZXRyaWNfa2V5In0.eyJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJUN0dBbWViNGgzVU04bE1wUm10MTJHT2M1dXYzRkI4aCIsImV4cCI6MTU3ODQ2Mzc4Nywic2NvcGUiOlsidmlld2FibGVzOnJlYWQiXSwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cHM6Lyp9hdXRvZGVzay5jb20vYXVkL2p3dGV4cDYwIiwianRpIjoiRE1jWTVDVUVqNmo5QkdjM0F2N1VFN1NKdWZvZ0dQV1pIbUlrdUJPTEIzczJ4Ym1YakpnVVZyZzZVZnZhZDA3UyJ9.j3T1cThwAs9p8LNasuR7S8WXlGqR1lU6kX-RY8XW5QU';
         var timeInSeconds = 36000; // Use value provided by Forge Authentication (OAuth) API
         onTokenReady(token, timeInSeconds);
     }
 };

 Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function() {

     var htmlDiv = document.getElementById('forgeViewer');
     viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(htmlDiv);
     //viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(htmlDiv);
     var startedCode = viewer.start();
     if (startedCode > 0) {
         console.error('Failed to create a Viewer: WebGL not supported.');
         return;
     }

     console.log('Initialization complete, loading a model next...');

 });

 var documentId = 'urn:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6dDdnYW1ljYjRoM3VtOGxtcHJtdDEyZ29jNXV2M2ZiOGhfdHV0b3JpYWxfYnVja2V0L1QwMDZfMTktQVJDLVpaLVlZWS1NMy1XRC0wMDUxLnJ2dA';
 Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);

 function onDocumentLoadSuccess(viewerDocument) {
     var defaultModel = viewerDocument.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry();
     viewer.loadDocumentNode(viewerDocument, defaultModel);
 }

 function onDocumentLoadFailure() {
     console.error('Failed fetching Forge manifest');
 }

 $(document ).ready(function() {
  $viewer = jQuery('#forgeViewer');
  
  // After a mouse click on 3D viewport, populate X/Y/Z of the intersection
     $viewer.on('click', function(ev) {
            
         if(viewer.getSelection()){
          
                mainviewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(  document.getElementById('forgeViewer') );

                // Other codes ...
                const selSet = mainviewer.getSelection();
                const targetElem = selSet[0];

                const model = mainviewer.model;
                const instanceTree = model.getData().instanceTree;
                const fragList = model.getFragmentList();

                let bounds = new THREE.Box3();

                instanceTree.enumNodeFragments( dbId, ( fragId ) => {
                    let box = new THREE.Box3();
                    fragList.getWorldBounds( fragId, box );
                    bounds.union( box );
                }, true );

                const position = bounds.center();

            }
        })
        
 });
```

```html
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="js/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/style.min.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.min.js"></script>
    
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }
        #forgeViewer {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            background-color: #F0F8FF;
        }
       
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="forgeViewer"></div>
<div>
</body>
```

I tried const bounds = document.getElementById('forgeViewer').getBoundingClientRect(); for getting bounds but it return me x =0 and y=0 for any selected component in viewer. 
I am using chrome only, not sure why its not working here....any other way to get cordinates
Actually my intention is to show a pop up window for selected component to add some custom data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code snippet you mentioned is for HTML DOM only. It will give you the DOM rect element of the DOM element with id `forgeViewer`, and cannot be used to retrieve info inside the viewer's 3d/2d world. Please use viewer API instead.

```
const viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(  document.getElementById('forgeViewer') );

// Other codes ...

const selSet = viewer.getSelection();
const targetElem = selSet[0];

const model = viewer.model;
const instanceTree = model.getData().instanceTree;
const fragList = model.getFragmentList();

let bounds = new THREE.Box3();

instanceTree.enumNodeFragments( dbId, ( fragId ) => {
    let box = new THREE.Box3();
    fragList.getWorldBounds( fragId, box );
    bounds.union( box );
}, true );

const position = bounds.center(); //!<<< This is the selected object's position in the viewer world
```

Comment: am getting error  "cannot read property getSelection  of undefined from viewer3d file...for code                    Viewer3D.prototype.getSelection = function () {
        return this.impl.selector.getSelection();
    };

Comment: <script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.min.js"></script>

Comment: You have to load model first, the above code didn't contain that part

Comment: Please check tutorial here to get started: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/viewer_basics/load-a-model/

Comment: I have added code above. I followed documentation, and I got this error on click of model which is already loaded in DOM...still not sure where I went wrong

Comment: Follow the tutorial Eason mentioned and look into 'react to events' part of it aswell. This will teach you how to properly react to viewer events using the functions Autodesk provides. Your code has alot of anomalies in it still that make this very hard to troubleshoot.

Comment: yes I fixed anomalies and I got cordinates. in above there is a small type, as dbid should be targetElem

Answer (score 0):

```
var _selectedModel = viewer.getAggregateSelection()[0].model;
```

this is used to find the model of a selected object in the viewer. You can also do this in an event listener. For example, you can use AGGREGATE_SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT. Then you can call _selectedModel and access coordinates, global offsets, 4-dimensional matrix and many more features.

```
_selectedModel.getGlobalOffset()
```

for example, this will give you the x, y, z coordinates.